# Instruct Photorec to look for a specific file

Tags: photorec

I want to recover a source code java  called **prog.java** using photorec, I have already enabled my custom signature to look only for **.java** files but it still produces too many files to search through.

Is there a way to search for and recover only my **prog.java**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General warning and tips

It is important to avoid writing files to the partition and file system, where you want to recover data, because you might overwrite the data, that you want to recover.

- Unmount the partition as soon as possible and avoid mounting it.
- If the data are very important, it is a good idea to clone the drive (or partition) and to do the recovery work on the cloned copy.

### PhotoRec

If I understand correctly, you can instruct PhotoRec to search for a specific file type, as identified by a data pattern that are characteristic for that kind of file. But I don't think you can make it search for a specific file name.

Please notice that PhotoRec is looking at the data 'on the drive' in a way that is independent of any list of file names and its pointers to the data locations.

### Other tools

There might be other tools, that can use a damaged list of file names and its pointers to the data.

- Linux **ext** file systems use indexed allocation where each file has it's own index block or inode. A file's inode has direct links to disk blocks as well as links to other indirect blocks.
- **NTFS** begins with the Master File Table (MFT) for a volume.  Every file in NTFS is described by one or more records in the MFT.
- **FAT32**: FAT stands for File Allocation Table and 32 means 32-bit.  The basic idea is that a section of disk is set aside to store a file allocation table that consists of entries for each block.

### Links

[CGSecurity - Data recovery: TestDisk & PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/)

[FAT, NTFS, and EXT File Systems... What's the Difference?](http://www.claytonstechnobabble.com/2011/08/fat-ntfs-and-ext-file-systems-whats.html)

[extundelete.sourceforge.net](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net)

[Five free portable recovery tools](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-free-portable-recovery-tools/)

Comment: Honestly I dont like Photorec. extundelete I wont even attempt to use it because I know I' d make a mess. But since I have Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows I will try with recuva from Windows and see what I get

Comment: I wish you good luck :-)

Comment: You can specify a single filename or directory or filenames with extundelete. Has to be remounted as read only though.